# Copy directory from sd card to "files" folder

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I would like to copy a directory from sd card (e.g `file:///storage/emulated/0/`MyDirectory) to `files` directory (`data/data/<app-id>/files`) using [cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file), there's already an example in [Cordova File API Documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html):

```
function win(entry) {
    console.log("New Path: " + entry.fullPath);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert(error.code);
}

function copyDir(entry) {
    var parent = document.getElementById('parent').value,
        parentName = parent.substring(parent.lastIndexOf('/')+1),
        newName = document.getElementById('newName').value,
        parentEntry = new DirectoryEntry(parentName, parent);

    // copy the directory to a new directory and rename it
    entry.copyTo(parentEntry, newName, success, fail);
}
```

I could find the way to declare paths according to cordova-plugin-file:

`var mySrcPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + "MyDirectory";` (for `file:///storage/emulated/0/`MyDirectory) and

`var myDesPath = cordova.file.dataDirectory;` (for `data/data/<app-id>/files`)

but didn't know the code of how to declare `DirectoryEntry` objects for `mySrcPath` and `myDesPath`

Could any one help me to make the example above clearer to solve my case, because my knowledge about javascript is not so good, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

In [Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#DirectoryEntry), you can find this quick example that uses getDirectory function of DirectoryEntry:

```
function success(parent) {
 console.log("Parent Name: " + parent.name);
}

function fail(error) {
 alert("Unable to create new directory: " + error.code);
}

// Retrieve an existing directory, or create it if it does not already exist
entry.getDirectory("newDir", {create: true, exclusive: false}, success, fail);
```

Comment: Do you know where `entry` variable comes from? Is it a built-in variable of Cordova

Comment: In fact, I didn't use it till now because I use [ngcordova file plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/) to get access to the device's files and directories